# Add image to the 3D canvas in Java3d

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

I am working on a project where I have to show a visualization of various shapes on the canvas. One way to do this is creating my own polygons. Is there any way I can add .png/.jpg images on the canvas?

Comment: What do you mean by adding images on the canvas? Do you want to see them inside your scene or over the canvas? I remind you that the official JogAmp forum is a better place to get help about Java3D: http://forum.jogamp.org/

Comment: Apologies for creating confusion. I wish to see them inside my scene.

Comment: Don't be sorry, I understand your position and I answered here: http://forum.jogamp.org/Add-image-to-the-3D-canvas-in-Java3d-tp4032246p4032247.html